# Creating QgsFeatureSink without using parameterAsSink

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, sink

I know I can create a (`QgsFeatureSink`, string) tuple by calling

```py
(sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(...)
```

However that requires me to pass an output layer as a parameter:

```py
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
        self.OUTPUT,
        self.tr('Some output layer'),
        QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon
    )
)
```

But in a lot of cases, I really don't want this feature layer as an output. I might use it only for temporary processing. For instance I might generate a number of features and then rasterize them and only present the rasterized result to the user.

How can I create a similar sink from code that only resides in memory during the processing of the algorithm, and is not presented to the user?

Comment: Maybe `QgsProcessingUtils.createFeatureSink()` can help you. Link to docs: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingUtils.html#a46a8d03b97cc27a13ba444634482ce50  And some examples: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?q=createFeatureSink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Ben's suggestion, you can use `createFeatureSink` as a drop-in replacement. The only thing to be aware of, is to use `memory:` as `destination` URI. Something that seems to be missing from [the official documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Processing/QgsProcessingUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingUtils.createFeatureSink)

```py
(sink, dest_id) = QgsProcessingUtils.createFeatureSink(
    'memory:',
    context,
    self.source.fields(),
    self.source.wkbType(),
    self.source.sourceCrs()
)
```